# Inner loop performed only once

Tags: python, for-loop

I have the following piece of code:

```
heList = open(self.IAM_he_List, 'r')
appsList = open(self.IAM_appsList, 'r')
resultsFile = open(self.IAM_Tests_Results, 'w')

for line in heList:
    __splitLine = line.split(',')
    heNum = __splitLine[0]
    roleName = __splitLine[1].rstrip()
    for app in appsList:
            resultsFile.writelines(heNum +  "," + roleName + "," + app.rstrip() + "," + "," + "," + "\n")
```

I expect it to iterate through one inner loop for each outer loop, however it seems that the inner loop is only executed once. I guess I'm missing something basic here. Any ideas?

Comment: There don't seem to be an inner loop and an outer loop here; there are just two loops. Is this how your code is indented in your actual source file?

Comment: the "inner loop" executes only once because it's not in really an inner loop

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, it seems that the code gets a different formatting here. In my original code the indentation is different.

Comment: I have changed the formatting. Now it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`appslist` is a file iterator. After the first loop, the iterator is exhausted (because the end of the file has been reached). Subsequent `for` loops are therefore skipped.

You can either (assuming you really need to do this repeatedly) reset the file iterator by using `appslist.seek(0)`, or read the file into a list once and iterate over the list repeatedly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Shouldn't the inner for iterate each time from beginning for each `line` in `heList`? How can this code be changed in order to do that?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't consider the fact that this is a file and not a list. Adding `appslist.seek(0)` after each inner loop worked perfectly.